# Using JavaScript to get random 2-digit numbers in a specific range where both the 1st and 2nd digits are constrained

Tags: javascript, math, random

I've got a bit of an interesting mathematical puzzle to solve.

I'm writing a test to verify that values outside of a range of a field in a window are not allowed to be input. For the most part this is extremely easy.

I'm using a function like this:

```
function getRanInt(min, max)
{
    let min = Math.ceil(min);
    let max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

to set the range of "erroneous" values I want to test.

However, there is one field which throws a wrench in this method. One field has constraints on each digit. So the first digit can only be between 0-7 and the second digit can only be between 0-3.

My first thought was to simply concatenate two numbers together that I could separately constrain like this:

```
let m1_1;
let m1_2;

m1_1 = getRanInt(8,9);
m1_2 = getRanInt(4,9);

m1 = m1_1.toString() + m1_2.toString();
m1 = Number(m1);
```

until I thought about it for half a second and realized that this would only get me erroneous values > 83 but leave out an entire array of possible erroneous values like 24, 36, 18 etc...

I've been wracking my brain to try and come up with a solution that isn't massively convoluted but I've been drawing a blank. I thought I'd turn to you fine braniacs here and see if you could maybe help unstick my gears.

ADDITIONAL: If anyone's interested, the tool tip for the field in question explicitly says this:

```
2 Digits:
1st = 0 - 7
2nd = 0 - 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test all the incorrect values, you can combine solution that provided by you with the second set of values, that are accessible using your functions in the following way:

```
let result;
if(Math.round(Math.random()))
{
let m1_1;
let m1_2;

m1_1 = getRanInt(8,9);
m1_2 = getRanInt(0,9);

let m1 = m1_1.toString() + m1_2.toString();
result = Number(m1);
}
else
{
    let m2_1;
let m2_2;

m2_1 = getRanInt(0,7);
m2_2 = getRanInt(4,9);

let m2 = m2_1.toString() + m2_2.toString();
result = Number(m2);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it does the trick! I've modified my original getRanInt function so that max = max + 1 to combat the floor function always pulling away from the actual maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

I just wonder why the users can fill in the wrong values in the first place.

You can stop this from happening  either by [restricting the numbers](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) the user can put in an input, by using a [number input](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp), or a [range slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp).

I will show you how it can look like below, but you can go even further and override any input the user have done, based on a `pattern` or `min` and `max` value - or to check if the input validates.

The slider doesn't need extra code so that's probably the preferred way.

```js
function updateLabel(rangeId, rangeValue) {
  let labelElement = document.getElementById(rangeId + "label");

  if (labelElement) {
    labelElement.innerHTML = rangeValue;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

input:invalid + label,
.range-container > label {
  display: inline-block;
}


.range-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h4>Text Input</h4>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="0-7" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-7]{1}">
  <label>A number between 0 and 7 is required.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="0-3" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-7]{1}">
  <label>A number between 0 and 3 is required.</label>
</div>

<hr/>

<h4>Number Input</h4>
<div>
  <input type="number" placeholder="0-7" min="0" max="7">
  <label>A number between 0 and 7 is required.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" placeholder="0-3" min="0" max="3">
  <label>A number between 0 and 3 is required.</label>
</div>
<hr/>

<h4>Range Slider</h4>
<div class="range-container">
  <input type="range" oninput="updateLabel(this.id, this.value)" id="first" min="0" max="7" value="0">
  <label id="firstlabel">0</label>
</div>
<div class="range-container">
  <input type="range" oninput="updateLabel(this.id, this.value)" id="second" min="0" max="3" value="0">
  <label id="secondlabel">0</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, you got me. There are a lot of coding decisions the developers make that seem "bad"... but I'm just writing code to make sure their bad code works. I'm trying to write a bit of code right now that can test for all non-octal numbers because they only allow octal numbers to be used in certain fields but still allow the input of all decimal numbers..... :D